# set title with *ngIf else

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I use Angular 5 and the title of a popup shout be dependet on a boolean.
When the property isEditing is true, the title should be "edit user".
Otherwise the title should be "add user".

How is the syntax of it?

```
<dxo-popup title="edit user" .../>
```

I search for some thing like:

Thanks for help!
Frank

Comment: I search for some thing like:
<dxo-popup *ngIf="isEditing" than title="edit user" else title="add user" .../>

Answer (score 5):

The other solutions require you to either change your HTML, or add unecessary code to your Typescript.

Here is a ternary :

```
<dxo-popup [title]="isEditing ? 'Edit user' : 'Add user'" .../>
```

Comment: I would not consider adding code to the component unnecessary, which would suggest that this is a bad thing. Some people might even call this clean code, where logic that is more complex than a `*ngIf="isEditing"` is delegated to the component.

Comment: As far as I can see, the styleguide proposes the opposite: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#put-presentation-logic-in-the-component-class (note that the logic there is simple, too)

Comment: Well, I didn't suggest that your answer is wrong. I merely pointed out that other answers to this question do a) not necessarily add unnecessary code, and b) might be a considered clean code for others.

Comment: Coming back to the styleguide: only because you can do something doesn't necessarily mean you should do it. To conclude: there is no right or wrong with the current answers, just a matter of style.

Comment: I'm removing my unecessary comments to answer to you, and conclude with this one : this solution is what the OP asked for, the others aren't.

Comment: What if I want to use one of my angular component's field in this string?

Answer (score 3):

I like to take functionality out of the template and move it into the component:

Component:

```
isEditing = true;

get title() {
  return this.isEditing ? 'edit user' : 'add user';
}
```

HTML Template:

```
<dxo-popup title="{{ title }}" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isEditing;then edit else add"></ng-container>

<ng-template #edit>edit user</ng-template>
<ng-template #add>add user</ng-template>
```

Comment: instead of <div> he can use <ng-container>, this will not generate another rendered html-tag

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a function in your component to return the text.

Component:

```
  isEditing = true;
  popupTitle(){
    return (this.isEditing ? "Edit User" : "Add User");
  }
```

HTML:

```
<dxo-popup title="{{popupTitle()}}" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this question and found a simple version of the answer, and I wish to add it here as a helpful reference.

```
<button title=" {{ condition ? 'Some TRUE text' : 'Some FALSE text'}}"> Test Button </button>
```